# LinkedIn's new share button still has old appearance

Tags: share, linkedin-api

LinkedIn claims to have updated their share button to a new appearance with a flatter style similar to facebook's. However, despite using their publisher code generator the appearance has not updated on my site.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
</script><script type="in/share" data-url="https://myurlhere.com" data-counter="right" data-showzero="right" ></script>
```

Anyone has any idea what I am missing?

Comment: As it turns out I wasn't missing anything. Apparently LinkenIn does some validation internally and after a small time lapse the button will automatically update to the new look without web administrators needing to make adjustments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appearance of the share buttons will updates automatically after a few days.

There is nothing extra that the site administrators need to do other than follow the developer instructions at https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share